# where should i get the id_rsa.pub File path

Tags: git

I was getting the public key denied after typeing the git clone , hence i have generate the SSH key but am not getting the path  C:\Users\MOHAS076/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in my C- drive in my window . how to get this .

Comment: This path will work if the file exists.. you probably have not created the `.ssh` directory yet? It might be a hidden directory, so set your explorer to show hidden files and directories as well.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=ssh+key+path+windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cloning a Git repository you should use your private key:
`C:\Users\MOHAS076/.ssh/id_rsa`

Alternatively you can correct the `/` to `\` but windows will find the correct file anyway. You can copy the path and paste it into Windows Explorer's address bar. If this finds the file the path is correct - otherwise the file does not exist there.

- The public key is put in GitLab/GitHub/any platform you use
- The private key is used on your machine only
- The default is your user directory in the `.ssh` directory - make sure it exists

Please post the error message if this does not fix your problem.